# iOS prototype to app

Tags: ios, core-data

I am developing a relatively simple new free iOS app. As it's free I decided to go straight for iOS 5 as a target to allow me to try out some new features, particularly story boards.

Once I've got my head around them storyboards are wonderful, I've written hardly any boilerplate code at all up the point of a working prototype.

My model at the moment is is non persistent, after all it's just a prototype, but I've started to wonder about the best way to make it persistent. The model consists of essentially a list of custom objects which contain text, images and locations.

And so to the questions.

If I have a fully working model in memory is there a relatively simple to convert that into a persistent core data representation ?

If I want to have synchronisation to a backend web service at some point will this help ?

Should I start again with a core data application and throw away the prototype ?

Answer (score 1):

All depends on your data set. If you have a large graph with relationships, Core Data might be a good idea. For simpler data sets, you could write it out to a .plist in the user's documents directory. For very small amounts of data, you could persist them into `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Dataset is a bit larger that NSUserDefaults would be useable for. Is managing images directly on the file system simple enough for a plist approach ?

Comment: Also whilst very simple the model will expand, already I see the need for secondary relationships to handle groups and multiple images per object.

Comment: It's certainly feasible. Just store URLs to the location of the images in the documents directory. If you decide to go with Core Data, you should know that it is now capable of handing external storage of files like images in iOS 5.0+ and Mac OS X 10.7+.